# How can my data on a simulated game's win or loss status, and its return rate, be harmonized?

Tags: c#, winforms, logic, simulation

I've coded a simulator in C# to repeatedly test the outcome of a certain casino-ish game.  In one example trial of the program, the output is a 63.4% game win ratio (where starting capital is doubled on a win and wiped out on a loss), yet from the same set of trials, the return rate for the game is calculated to be 95.3%, significantly less than breakeven.  Another trial similarly produced a 68% win ratio, but with a return average of only 96%.

**Desired Behavior:**  To produce the correct results in my outputted win/loss data, and "returnSamples" list (and by extension "returnAverage" as well).

**Specific Problem:**  The "returnAverage" variable shows an overall loss (~95% return rate where 100% is breakeven), but the win/loss record strongly favors wins (roughly 2/3 of games are won), and wins and losses are equal to each other in size.  More specifically, an individual element of "returnSamples" can show a return lower than 100% for a single game that was won.

**Code to Reproduce Problem** (I don't think I can successfully snip any of this to make it shorter, being that it's a debugging topic.)**:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace theBlindPainterTester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rn1_6 = new Random();
        float cost = 51;
        float baseBet = 50;
        static double startScore = 10000;
        static double score = startScore;
        double lowestScore = score;
        bool isRoundOver = false;

        OrderedColors[] panelColors = { OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless };

        int victories = 0;
        int losses = 0;

        double cycledPointsThisRound = 0;
        completedRoundData data = new completedRoundData(score, 0);
        List<double> returnSamples = new List<double>();
        double returnAverage = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strategyFileText;

            using (StreamReader strategyFile = new StreamReader("strategy.txt"))
            {
                strategyFileText = strategyFile.ReadToEnd();
            }

            string[] strats = strategyFileText.Split('\n');

            for (int h = 0; h < 1000000; h++)
            {
                int selectedPlay = selectPlay(strats);

                if (selectedPlay == 0)
                {
                    endRound();
                }
                else if (selectedPlay == 1 || selectedPlay == 3 || selectedPlay == 6)
                {
                    score = score - cost;
                    cycledPointsThisRound += cost;

                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedPlay; i++)
                    {
                        if (isRoundOver == false)
                        {
                            paintPanel();
                        }
                    }

                    payOut();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(selectedPlay + " is not a valid play");
                }
            }

            returnAverage = returnSamples.Average();
            richTextBox1.Text += "Win - loss record:  " + victories + " - " + losses + "   Return percentage:  " + (100 * returnAverage);
        }

        // Retrieves the appropriate game play for the current panel colors
        private int selectPlay(string[] strats)
        {
            int play = -2; // The value 0 has a specific meaning

            Array.Sort(panelColors);
            Array.Reverse(panelColors);

            foreach (string strat in strats)
            {
                string[] stratComponents = strat.Split(',');
                int matches = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
                {
                    if (stratComponents[j] == panelColors[j].ToString())
                    {
                        matches++;
                    }
                }

                if (matches == 6)
                {
                    play = Convert.ToInt32(stratComponents[6]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return play;
        }

        // Paints a single randomly selected panel
        private void paintPanel()
        {
            int primedPanel = rn1_6.Next(1, 7);

            if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Colorless)
            {
                panelColors[primedPanel - 1] = OrderedColors.Purple;
            }
            else if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Purple)
            {
                panelColors[primedPanel - 1] = OrderedColors.Blue;
            }
            else if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Blue)
            {
                panelColors[primedPanel - 1] = OrderedColors.Green;
            }
            else if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Green)
            {
                panelColors[primedPanel - 1] = OrderedColors.Yellow;
            }
            else if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Yellow)
            {
                panelColors[primedPanel - 1] = OrderedColors.Orange;
            }
            else if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Orange)
            {
                panelColors[primedPanel - 1] = OrderedColors.Red;
            }
            else if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Red)
            {
                endRound();
            }
        }

        // Adjusts score and takes action if the game is over
        private void payOut()
        {
            int numPurple = 0;
            int numBlue = 0;
            int numGreen = 0;
            int numYellow = 0;
            int numOrange = 0;
            int numRed = 0;

            int numNonZeros = 0;

            for (int panel = 0; panel <= 5; panel++)
            {
                if (panelColors[panel] == OrderedColors.Purple)
                {
                    numPurple++;
                }

                if (panelColors[panel] == OrderedColors.Blue)
                {
                    numBlue++;
                }

                if (panelColors[panel] == OrderedColors.Green)
                {
                    numGreen++;
                }

                if (panelColors[panel] == OrderedColors.Yellow)
                {
                    numYellow++;
                }

                if (panelColors[panel] == OrderedColors.Orange)
                {
                    numOrange++;
                }

                if (panelColors[panel] == OrderedColors.Red)
                {
                    numRed++;
                }
            }

            if (numPurple != 0)
            {
                numNonZeros++;
            }

            if (numBlue != 0)
            {
                numNonZeros++;
            }

            if (numGreen != 0)
            {
                numNonZeros++;
            }

            if (numYellow != 0)
            {
                numNonZeros++;
            }

            if (numOrange != 0)
            {
                numNonZeros++;
            }

            if (numRed != 0)
            {
                numNonZeros++;
            }

            switch (numPurple)
            {
                case 3:
                    score += (.2 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    score += baseBet;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    score += (5 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    score += (10 * baseBet);
                    break;
            }

            switch (numBlue)
            {
                case 3:
                    score += (.4 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    score += (2 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    score += (10 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    score += (20 * baseBet);
                    break;
            }

            switch (numGreen)
            {
                case 3:
                    score += (.6 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    score += (3 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    score += (15 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    score += (40 * baseBet);
                    break;
            }

            switch (numYellow)
            {
                case 3:
                    score += (.8 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    score += (4 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    score += (20 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    score += (60 * baseBet);
                    break;
            }

            switch (numOrange)
            {
                case 3:
                    score += baseBet;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    score += (5 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    score += (40 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    score += (80 * baseBet);
                    break;
            }

            switch (numRed)
            {
                case 3:
                    score += (1.2 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    score += (6 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    score += (80 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    score += (100 * baseBet);
                    break;
            }

            if (numPurple + numBlue == 6 && numPurple != 0 && numBlue != 0)
            {
                score += (2 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numBlue + numGreen == 6 && numBlue != 0 && numGreen != 0)
            {
                score += (4 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numGreen + numYellow == 6 && numGreen != 0 && numYellow != 0)
            {
                score += (5 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numYellow + numOrange == 6 && numYellow != 0 && numOrange != 0)
            {
                score += (7 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numOrange + numRed == 6 && numOrange != 0 && numRed != 0)
            {
                score += (10 * baseBet);
            }

            if (numPurple + numBlue + numGreen == 6 && numPurple != 0 && numGreen != 0)
            {
                score += (.4 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numBlue + numGreen + numYellow == 6 && numBlue != 0 && numYellow != 0)
            {
                score += (.6 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numGreen + numYellow + numOrange == 6 && numGreen != 0 && numOrange != 0)
            {
                score += (1.6 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numYellow + numOrange + numRed == 6 && numYellow != 0 && numRed != 0)
            {
                score += (2.4 * baseBet);
            }

            if (numNonZeros == 4)
            {
                score += (.2 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numNonZeros == 5)
            {
                score += (.6 * baseBet);
            }
            else if (numNonZeros == 6)
            {
                score += (20 * baseBet);
            }

            outcomeCheck();
        }

        private double returnRate(double scoreData, double cycles)
        {
            if (startScore != 0 && cycles != 0)
            {
                return Math.Pow((scoreData / startScore), (1D / cycles));
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        private void endRound()
        {
            isRoundOver = true;

            data.endingScore = score;
            data.cycledPointTotal += cycledPointsThisRound;
            cycledPointsThisRound = 0;

            for (int panel = 0; panel <= 5; panel++)
            {
                panelColors[panel] = OrderedColors.Colorless;
            }
        }

        private void outcomeCheck()
        {
            if (score <= lowestScore)
            {
                lowestScore = score;
            }

            if (score >= 2 * startScore)
            {
                victories++;
                richTextBox1.Text += (lowestScore + "\n");
                returnSamples.Add(returnRate(data.endingScore, data.cycledPointTotal / startScore));

                endRound();

                data.endingScore = 0;
                data.cycledPointTotal = 0;
                score = startScore;
                lowestScore = startScore;
            }
            else if (score < cost)
            {
                losses++;
                richTextBox1.Text += ("0\n");
                returnSamples.Add(returnRate(data.endingScore, data.cycledPointTotal / startScore));

                endRound();

                data.endingScore = 0;
                data.cycledPointTotal = 0;
                score = startScore;
                lowestScore = startScore;
            }

            isRoundOver = false;
        }
    }

    public class completedRoundData
    {
        public double endingScore;
        public double cycledPointTotal;

        public completedRoundData(double eS, double cPT)
        {
            endingScore = eS;
            cycledPointTotal = cPT;
        }
    }

    public enum OrderedColors
    {
        Colorless,
        Purple,
        Blue,
        Green,
        Yellow,
        Orange,
        Red
    }
}
```

http://hastebin.com/yuvudibugo.coffee

**Explanation of Problem Statement:**  The core of the code simulates one million turns of game play, and outputs resulting statistical information.  It determines how many times the starting score is doubled (win) and how many times it goes to zero (loss), after which the score is reset to the starting amount.

There are a few lines of code, added to this core, which are used to calculate the overall return rate percentage (i.e. 100% means breakeven).  Lines 29-32 (declarations), 61, 79, 80, 374-384, 390-392, 411, 415, 416, 424, 428, 429, and 438-448 are relevant to this task (I may have missed a line or two, but those are the relevant variables).

The simulation is composed of "rounds."  After a round, the game state is reset, with the exception of the user's score.  My program's execution also divides into larger segments, which I call "games."  A game ends when the starting score is doubled, or hits (nearly) zero (technically when it falls below the cost per turn to play, since the user could not pay to take the next turn); then a new game begins.  If a game (or the one million iterations of my whole program) ends in the middle of a round, I exclude the information from the unfinished round from my return percentage calculations, since the win/loss record would also not reflect this.  The object named "data" collects data at the end of each round to make these calculations possible.

When I try to debug the program, most but NOT all of the elements in the returnSamples list show over 100% for the victorious games, and under 100% for the losing games (each element in the list corresponds to one game).  A pastebin comparing the win/loss status to the list can be found at [hastebin.com/sehigaqifi.md](http://hastebin.com/sehigaqifi.md) for one instance of executing the program.  The column "Low" is zero if the user lost the starting capital before doubling it, and non-zero if the user doubled the starting capital before losing it.  I am NOT claiming that the value in the "Low" column indicates (aside from its being zero or non-zero) the expected return rate, nor that the win rate determines return rate or vice-versa.  Instead, the problem is that several games with a positive overall outcome (a win instead of a loss) yield a return rate of less than 100%, such as hastebin lines 3, 60, and 246. Interestingly, it seems to be many of the 90-some% return rates that this problem applies to, rather than those which are even lower.

I have been unsuccessful in further debugging attempts, as well as trying to manually spot the problem in the code.  Can anyone see a reason that the percentages in returnSamples (or the win/loss outcome of a round) would be incorrect?

Comment: returnRate(data.endingScore, data.cycledPointTotal / startScore) and private double returnRate(double scoreData, double cycles) => looks screwy, the implementation of returnRate only makes sense if your feeding in the number of games as cyles and cycledPointTotal/startScore seems unlikely to be that...

Comment: I looked at is this way.  If you bring $100 to a slot machine (costs $2 per play, and pays out in money not chips), and play 100 times, you've cycled $200.  This is 2 "cycles" of your starting capital, regardless of how many plays you made, or what is defined a one "game."  This 2 is the number you need to set up the equation e = $100 * (r ^ 2), where e is whatever value you have after the 200 rounds, and r is the return rate you're solving for.  Perhaps I'm still missing something though.